# Why I can only get 2 monitors to work and 3rd don't with 3 port video card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have total 3 monitors.

I have ATI Graphics card with 3 ports. 
2 HDMI and 1 DVI (looks like).

```
                       (Video card port    -->  Monitor port)
 1)   HP L0245W          (connected DVI      to   VGA         )(working)
 2)   HP L2045W          (connected HDMI     to   DVI         )(working)
 3)   HP Compaq LA2205wg (connected HDMI     to   HDMI        )(not working)
```

if I unplug cable 1 from video card then monitor 3 works,
if I unplug cable 2 and plug 1 back in then 3 works.

How can I get all 3 working ?

This is video card I have
[ATI HD4600](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/news/amd_set_launch_ati_hd_4600_its_answer_nvdia_geforce_9500_series_september_10) 
[Photo of Video Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUGFS.png)

Comment: Your video card does not support hooking up three monitors at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, that graphics card only supports 2 simultaneous monitors.

Edit: If you're willing to spend some money, you could go for something like a Matrox display splitter (http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/), but for that price you may as well just buy a new graphics card that supports triple monitors. ([random example](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161379)) There doesn't seem to be a software fix to this problem, it's just a limitation of the availible hardware.

Comment: that is so messed up, why do they even put 3 ports on it. thanks for info.. how can I get 3rd monitor to work? I also have a built in VGA port on motherboard can I use that?

Comment: Hmm, what are the specs of your computer (specifically CPU and motherboard, that might enable graphics on it?)

Comment: 4 GB Ram, 3.16Ghz, what info do you need?

Comment: Well, for your motherboard to have graphics output capability, to my knowledge, it would need either an Intel Core i3/i5/i7 CPU, an onboard integrated graphics card, or an AMD A-series APU. Does your VGA port work by itself?

Comment: You could also just get a newer video card - all current gen Radeons should support 3+ simultaneous outputs (although you may need an active DisplayPort adapter to get them all lit, since I assume your monitors don't have DP onboard).

Comment: No my VGA port doesn't work by itself, I just tired it, but my device manager shows 3 monitors if I plugin all 3 into graphics card

Comment: @shinrai no - not all radeons support 3 monitors, they have mostly only 3 different outputs.

Comment: @Offler See MarcusJ's comment on the other answer (no relation :P); cards with Eyefinity support will run 3 monitors simultaneously, and that's most of the current generation.

Comment: That's essentially all of the current generation, really - the support is in the base level chipset and has been for several years.  The only cards that shouldn't do it are ones that don't physically have the ports or have been altered in oddball ways by the OEM.

Comment: @user635600 - You'll see all three because the card can recognize them, but it's incapable of sending a signal to all of them simultaneously.  This is the expected behavior.

Comment: @marcus: most are not all. Even with MOst you will have problems ig you try something like: have 2 outputs with 2560*1440 each (learned that the hard way - most new AMD workstation cards do not support his setup...)

Comment: @offler - I deal with this niche as my day job.  You're simply wrong, sorry.  (Your particular example should work fine on any current chipset if you're using DisplayPort.)

Comment: @shinrai For this particular example use a Hazro 32" monitor. It gets its data only over Dual-Link DVI-I - no display port at all (this is the setup of some low cost high-def monitors. ) You get them to work with a real Dual-Link card which has 24+5 pins. Also if you get a mac, a dvi to duallink adapter and a 30” Apple Cinema HD Display you will soon notice that you have problems with a second one. If you try to use them on something like a FirePro 2270 (AMD Workstation Card) no high-res monitor will run at all... the put the max res. for the case that you use 2 monitors on the page(mon1+mon2)

Comment: @Offler - That's not a problem with the chipset, that's a problem with the cabling and the cards.  You should have no problem ever running dual-link DVI with an active DP-to-DLDVI adapter off a DisplayPort.  The 2270 doesn't have one since it's an entry level card that's sort of deliberately lacking functionality in order to hit a very low 15W TDP (and fits my criteria of "The only cards that shouldn't do it are ones that don't physically have the ports").

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly have you verified that all three monitors work on their own? Also make sure that your video card supports driving three monitors at once.

Comment: Yes, they do, I use to use 3rd, monitor with laptop via HDMI and on my desktop if I unplug first monitor 3rd and 2nd monitor works, how do I know my video card supports 3 monitor at once? my video card has 3 ports.

Comment: You have a few options, if you're not going to be gaming you can use the integrated GPU (assuming your processor has one, and your motherboard has an available output) you can also buy a newer GPU (make SURE it supports driving 3 monitors, Eyefinity is the marketing name from ATI associated with driving 3+ monitors).

Comment: I use it for work :), I do not want to spend my own money on works computer, there is a built in VGA on my mother board.

Comment: Then you should be able to plug in your third monitor on the VGA port Protip: plug in the lowest res monitor into the VGA port.

Comment: I tried, my VGA doesn't work by itself, but my device manager shows 3 monitors if I plugin all 3 into graphics card

Comment: Gooling for the manual yields this page: http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-4000/hd-4600/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-4600-specifications.aspx  then in the specs part of the page: **two independent display controllers**      Drive two displays simultaneously with independent resolutions, refresh rates, color controls and video overlays for each display --- So this ATI card can only run two of them. For more you either need an extra GPU (and drivers and OS support), or a card which supports more simultaneous outputs).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the DVI and the HDMI output are the same with change at the connector end. In order for DVI to work, the circuit is directed there cutting off the HDMI output and vice versa. All you need is a second graphics card (if you have another PCI-E 16x slot) to have more outputs. As a last resort, you can use a legacy PCI graphics card (you are not limited to very old cards, I have found a Zotac Geforce 610 PCI card, others may exist as well!) but performance will suffer because legacy PCI slots are too slow by PCI-E standards (16 times slower or more!)